# Index out of Range in a 'for' loop

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing, arcgis

I am working on a project converting a csv file into an ArcGIS shapefile, this involves writing output to a separate file. I have created a list for each column in each row and am trying to index column 36 and 37. However, I am getting a `list index out of range` error message when doing this. Any suggestions as to what I may be doing?

```
while line:
    count = count + 1
    line = inFile.readline()
    print 'Row', count, 'line info=', line[:72]
    lineList = line.split(',')
    newList = lineList[:72]
    print 'line info =', newList   
    for item in newList[36]:
        item.replace("", "0")
    for item in newList[37]:
        item.replace("", "0")
    newLine = ','.join(newList)
    newLine = newLine + '\n'   
    formatLine = newLine.replace("/","_")
    outFile.write(formatLine)
```

Comment: Have you tried using something like for count, line in enumerate(infile.readline()): #do work? It will save a lot of your managing and checking. It will stop as soon as readline() hits the end of the file and mean you don't have to worry about that index out of range error at all.

Comment: Not sure if you are aware of it but there is a [**Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/) that specialises in questions like this - at least once it gets beyond the Python syntax and into the shapefile format.

Answer (score 3):

It would help if you could edit the question to include which line the error says is having the index out of range problem.

I believe the issue is likely to be this:

```
while line: # line is something other than whitespace
    line = inFile.readline() # next line becomes whitespace, there might be a trailing newline character in the file
    ...
    newList = line.split(',')[:72] # Even if line.split(',') doesn't return a list with at least 72 values, there will not be an error here- it will merely return a shorter list.
    for item in newList[36]: # newList is probably an empty list at this point.
    ...
```

On a side note, I typed the following into the Python shell:

```
>>> bool("")
False
>>> bool(" ")
True
>>> bool("\n")
True
```

As you can see, if there is a line that has only a space in it, then the loop would've continued as well.